# Why does HttpClient.PostAsync fail to return in a WPF environment?

Tags: c#, wpf, http

I have a piece of code that loads data from a web service :

```
        client = new HttpClient(handler) {Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60)};
        var post = await client.PostAsync(url, new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters));
```

When I run this in the stand-alone applications - one of which is WPF, the other is WinForms - this works perfectly OK.

However, I also have a version of this embedded in a larger WPF application. In both cases, when the embedded version is used, the application hangs on the post line.

I have checked at the web service end, and on fiddler, and it is definitely sending the request, and the response is being returned. It seems as if the PostAsync is just not getting the returned response, and so not being able to progress. Is there something I need to do to enable this to function?

All of the HTTP request and response looks fine, so I don't think it is anything to do with that. It is just the capture of this response.

Comment: You might be running into a deadlock. Please also provide the surrounding code, otherwise it is difficult to tell where the problem might be.

Comment: You are calling Result or Wait somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem recently, and it was solved by using `ConfigureAwait(false)`, like this:

```
var post = await client
                 .PostAsync(url, new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters))
                 .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked for me as well! Is there a reason this needs to be added?